# org.json.JSONObject.getLong gives imprecise result

Tags: java, android, json, type-conversion, long-integer

[image: Wrong precision in Long conversion]

In android, as we can see attached figure,
the json that I received from server is "id=-705156352446547**2446**"
but the code `jsonObject.getLong("id")` gives -705156352446547**2512**.

I can see every `getLong` conversion has imprecise result(or lose precision?) in last 4 digits.
Is there anything that I missed?

My settings: java 1.6.0_41, Android 4.1.2, IntelliJ 12 IDE.

Comment: is ID's type Long in DB?

Comment: @Daryn // Yes. can it be an issue? it's a general SpringFramework powered web service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Long.parseLong(jsonObject.getString("id"))` gives precise result.

Answer (score 1):

This would suggest the code for getLong() is doing some dubious conversion, possibly by using double.

This looks to be the case based on [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13831) issue report. Looks to have been fixed in a later version.

Comment: Thanks - I ran into the same bug and updating json.org to version 20141113 fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this problem very recently..
Solved it by using the code:

```
Long.valueOf(jarray.getString((index)))
```

Comment: As a matter of fact... even json.org's 20140107 version did solve the issue.